# Is there any other way of resolving null safety migration errors instead of manually?

Tags: flutter, dart, migration, dart-null-safety, flutter2.0

I just updated my application and I have the following:

**- flutter version: 2.3.0-1.0.pre**

**- flutter channel: dev**

**- number of packages: 50**

**- migration errors & warnings: 3k+**

Is there any other solution instead of fixing the migration errors manually?

Comment: Is this before or after you ran `dart migrate`

Comment: check out this -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bvq7wbn4VAA&t=196s